# How to view event details from another user's calendar on your calendar?

Tags: community, sharing, event, calendar, admin

I have two Users : `Bob` and `Community User Calendar`

I have one public calendar that is shared with `Bob` : `Calendar One`

I have a community user : `John`

Bob assigns an event `HR BENEFITS` to `Calendar One` and adds `Community User Calendar` as an attendee for the event. `John` goes to his calendar (within a community) and adds `Community User Calendar` to his calendar. Now he's able to see the `HR BENEFITS` event on his calendar. When he hovers on top of the event, the fields that are visible are `Subject, Start Date, and End Date` and there is a `More Details` button on the card. When he clicks on `More Details` to see the full details of the event he's not able to access it.

How can I allow `John` to access the details for this event?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is working as designed.

At times, the coworker's Event will only show you the following fields:

Subject Location Start End All-Day Event Description

While the same event viewed by another user might see all of the event details.

> **Resolution:** This is expected behavior and occurs when the Event was created
> without any related records (such as the Name and Related To fields).
>
> Events that don't have related records associated with them are
> considered Private. Only an Event Owner or Users with "View All Data"
> permissions can view the full details of these Activities.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318130&type=1&language=en_US&mode=1

Comment: The only fields I'm able to see on hovering the event are `Subject, Start, and End` - how can I see the `Location` and `Event Description`? Those are the fields I wish to see too @Anudeep